# Toggle Icon-bar color change on hover using Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggle

I am trying to make the .icon-bar class change color when you hover over it. I got the toggle button to change color and the icon-bar using:

```
.navbar-preheader .navbar-toggle {
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.navbar-preheader .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.navbar-preheader .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
}
```

The hover code I used was:

```
.navbar-preheader .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

But this is basically making each icon-bar change color, individually (see below), but they should all change color at once...

[image] [image]

I am sure it's something silly I am missing, but any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are wanting to change the background color when hovering over the parent element, therefore the `:hover` pseudo class should be after `.navbar-toggle` as opposed to the `.icon-bar`. In other words, you should use the selector `.navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3mbLg8f/)

```
.navbar-preheader .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for the information, that makes total sense now.